# Scale image height to browser window

Tags: javascript, css

Here is my image: http://cameronlimbrick.com/work/visual-art/paintings/item/thoughts

I would like to keep the existing maximum height, however, when the window is not tall enough to fit the entire image, I would like it to automatically shrink to fit the height. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's should work!

```
$(document).ready(){
   var h = $(window).height();
   if (h < 755)
   {
       $('.img.your-image-class').css("max-height",h + "px")
   }
}
```

Comment: no need to use javascript when the problem can be solved in pure css - just sayin'! ;P

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
img.your-image-class {
    height: 100%; //automatically retains aspect ratio
    max-height: 755px; //don't let it get bigger than this (755px is its current height I checked your link
}
```